# Appending a GET variable on a URL without knowing if it already has variables in it

Tags: php, get

I have a page into which I want to output an `a` element which links to the current page with the addition of a GET variable in a certain case. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $URI=home_url(  ).$Path;
    if($_GET['showall']==1) 
        {
        $URI = strtok($URI, '?'); //This removes the GET variables
        $showWhat = "Show 12 per Page";
        } 
    else 
        {
        $URI .= '?' . http_build_query(array('showall'=>1));
        $showWhat="Show All";
        }
?>
```

So what it does is if `showall` is 1 it just returns the URL of the current page without the `showall` variable on the end. If it isn't 1 then it appends `?showall=1` to the end of the URL.

This works great if there is not already another GET variable in the URL. If there is I get a URL like this:

`http://example.com?orderby=price?showall=1`

This clearly doesn't work as there is a missing `&amp;` between the variables.

How can I modify my code to work if there is already a GET variable present.

Please take into account that if showall=1 then I want to output the URL with the other GET variables except showall. E.g `http://example.com?orderby=price?`. I beleive just using what I have used will strip all the GET variables off.

(This is a wordpress site so `home_url()` is used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

`$URI .= '?' . http_build_query(array_merge($_GET,array('showall'=>1)));`

L.E: 
Maybe:

```
if($_GET['showall']==1) {
    $get = $_GET;
    unset($get['showall']);//since you don't want this anymore
    $URI = home_url('your-path-here') . '?'. http_build_query($get);
}
```

Please note, `home_url()` can take a uri argument, so pass the relative url to the home_url() function(i.e: `home_url('plugins/superplugin/the-page.php')`).

Comment: That is great but the only issue is if showall=1 then all GETs are stripped off the URL, not just `showall`

Comment: looks like it'll work. I'll test when I get back to my dev computer and report back. Many thanks